# How to remove non latest images using Bash

Tags: bash, docker

I want to delete non latest intermediate image with the label from docker. I used the below command, it works if there is more than 1 image, but if there is exactly 1 image, then it is deleting that image and again caching will happen from the next build. I'm new to Bash Scripting, any help would be highly appreciated.

What I want

```
if image_ids_with_label>1:
delete_nonlatest_images
else:
pass
```

Bash Command

```
docker images --filter "label=ImageName="$LabelName --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | sort -nr | tail -n -1  | cut -f2 | xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo docker rmi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good fix is probably to replace the pipeline with a simple Awk script which doesn't print anything if there is only one line.

```
docker images --filter "label=ImageName=$LabelName" --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' |
sort -nr |
awk -F '\t' 'END { if(NR>1) print $2 }' |
xargs --no-run-if-empty sudo docker rmi
```

Also notice how you want `$LabelName` inside the quotes, just in case it contains a shell metacharacter. (See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).)

Your attempt used `tail -n -1` which only prints the last line; if you really wanted to print all the lines except the first, that would be

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1 { print $2 }'
```

(and the corresponding `tail` invocation would be `tail -n +2`).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This is only showing the oldest container ID. But I want to delete everything but the latest. Could you please help.
`jenkins@Jenkins-x-x-x-x:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/devops$ docker images --filter "label=ImageName=devops_SellerInterface" --format '{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}' | sort -nr | awk -F '\t' 'END { if(NR>1) print $2 }'
47e46ed43b91`

Comment: I updated the question slightly; if that still doesn't cut it for you, please _explain_ how it's insufficient.